# put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, put

I am new in Django and I am trying to update record. but when I run `put` method, An error show like that =>

> put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Here is my view =>

```
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Allowance

from .serializers import AllowanceSerializer

# Create your views here.




class AllowanceAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,pk=None):
        if pk:
            allowance=get_object_or_404(Allowance.objects.all(),pk=pk)
            serializer = AllowanceSerializer(allowance)
            return Response({serializer.data})
        allowance=Allowance.objects.all()
        serializer = AllowanceSerializer(allowance,many=True)
        return Response({"allowance":serializer.data})        


    def put(self,request,pk):
        save_allowance = get_object_or_404(Allowance.objects.all(),pk=pk)
        data = request.data.get('allowance')
        serializer = AllowanceSerializer(instance=save_allowance,data=data,partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True):
            allowance_saved=serializer.save()

        return Response({"sucess": "Allowance '{}' updated successfully".format(allowance_saved.AllowID)})

    def delete(self,request,pk):
        #Get object with this pk
        allowance = get_object_or_404(Allowance.objects.all(),pk=pk)
        allowance.delete()
        return Response({"message":"Allowance with id '{}' has been deleted.".format(pk)},status=204)
```

Here is my url=>

```
from django.conf.urls import url


from .views import AllowanceAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', AllowanceAPIView.as_view(), name='post-listcreate'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AllowanceAPIView.as_view(), name='post-listcreate')
]
```

Get method and post method are ok, Just happen in `put` method and delete not testing yet. Please help.

Comment: Well, you've made the `put` method require a pk in the URL. Are you providing it? In any case, you should probably use a ViewSet with a router rather than doing this

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Thanks, I am new and honestly, May I know how to provide pk key?

Comment: As I said, it's in the URL. What URL are you using for the PUT?

Comment: I am just trying by Django Rest Framework default panel and my url is like that => http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/allowances_mas/

Comment: @DanielRoseman, And then I just put JSON format string in Put text box and click put button.

Comment: But like I said twice, you need the PK in the URL. You've even made a pattern for it. What don't you understand, and why did you make that pattern if you don't realise you need that PK? Your URL should be `127.0.0.1:8000/api/allowances_mas/XXX/` where XXX is the ID of the object you want to update.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I changed my request URL and it was worked. but now it happens again. This times I have no clue. Can u help me?